# Matrix equation align - letters and matrices

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I am trying to align a matrix equation so that the alignment it with the top of the column matrix A (not the centre as it is at the moment). Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{pmatrix}  && A^T &&  \end{pmatrix}  \textbf{B} \begin{pmatrix} \\ A \\ \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  \\ C \\ \\ \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}  && A^T &&  \end{pmatrix} \textbf{B} \begin{pmatrix} \\ y \\ \\ \end{pmatrix
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example, there is no preamble in your example. Plus this is completely wrong `\mathbf{\large{A$^\text{T}$}}`, (a) `\large` does not take argumetns, (b) you are already in math mode so I do not understand the intension with the `A$^\text{T}$`. Please update your example.

Comment: cheers, was just a culmination of lots of changes I had made. sorry to make it unclear

Comment: Your code snippets are currently not compilable.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you ask, but perhaps related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/matrix-decomposition-dimensions-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a stackable matrix to insert your `A^T` in the top row so it aligns vertically with the top row of `B`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bm{A}^T \bm{B} =
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    (\begin{array}{c}
      \quad \bm{A} \quad
    \end{array}) \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
  \end{array}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathstrut \\ \bm{B} \\ \mathstrut
  \end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

The use of `\mathstrut` is not all that necessary here.

I prefer the regular notation, to the left of the equal sign.