# Counting the number of occurrences of a string in an argument to a macro & replicating a string

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment

Based on the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/matrix-equation-align-letters-and-matrices/223503#223503) question, I've written a macro that returns a dot product with the top of the column array lined up properly with the top of the row array.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\myDotProduct}[3]{
        \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
         \begin{bmatrix}
            #1
         \end{bmatrix}  #3
        \end{array}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            #2
        \end{bmatrix}
        \mathstrut
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\myDotProduct{a & b}{z_1 \\ z_2}{\\ \\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It would be *much* more satisfactory if I could eliminate the third argument, by counting the number of `\\`'s that appear in the second argument, then using `\expr` to add one to this count, and then inserting the required number of `\\`'s in the appropriate place. But

1. I don't know how to count the number of occurrences of `\\` in the second argument
2. I don't know how to implement the concept:  output `n` replicas of `\\`

If there's no answer to (1) but an answer to (2), then a second best solution would be to replace the third argument `{\\ \\}` in the above macro with `{2}`, then use the answer to (2) to do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something else? Instead of inserting an appropriate number of `\\` as part of the *first* matrix, align the *second* matrix at the `t`op using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\myDotProduct}[3]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      #1
    \end{bmatrix}  #3
  \end{array}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    #2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \mathstrut
  }

\newcommand{\newDotProduct}[2]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
    #1
  \end{bmatrix}
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{$\begin{bmatrix}
    #2
  \end{bmatrix}$}
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \myDotProduct{a & b & c}{z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3 \\ z_4}{\\ \\ \\ \\}
\]

\[
  \newDotProduct{a & b & c}{z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3 \\ z_4}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The aspect is horrible, but you're the judge. Instead of doing complicated things you can use `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{delarray}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myDotProduct}[2]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}%
  \begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}c@{}}\rbrack#2\end{array}
  \end{array}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x=\myDotProduct{a & b}{z_1 \\ z_2}+
\myDotProduct{a & b & c}{u \\ v \\ w}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The outer `array` ensures global vertical centering.

[image]

If you want to go with the counting:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myDotProduct}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}
  \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq } { \\ }
  \end{array}
  \begin{bmatrix} #2 \end{bmatrix}
  \mathstrut
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
x=\myDotProduct{a & b}{z_1 \\ z_2}+
\myDotProduct{a & b & c}{u \\ v \\ w}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The function `\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq` returns the items in the second arguments (taking `\\` as separator).

Comment: I'm going to go with @Werner's adjustbox suggestion, which seems very simple, but it's *really* helpful to know how to count things in tex, Thanks