# Typesetting matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, documentation, tutorials

Here's a very general question: how would you guys write out a tutorial on matrix multiplication? Maybe with indicative arrows in order to show which line associates with its correspondent column, I really don't know how I would typeset these on LaTeX. Could you kindly give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is very opinion based question and actually is not related to (la) tex problems.

Comment: I think it actually is, if you follow the way I've asked: how could I correlate two matrices with arrows, for example, in a way I could correlate the terms that'd be multiplied. I couldn't figure out myself how would I do such a thing.

Comment: than pleas show us what you try so far and provide at least a sketch what you like to obtain ...

Comment: This doesn't exactly give you what you ask, but it may be a good starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/matrix-decomposition-dimensions-diagram

Comment: That was good! It gave me some hints of how i'm going to proceed. I just needed this start, actually. Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an example using TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/):

> [image]
>
> ```
> % Author : Alain Matthes
> % Source : http://altermundus.com/pages/examples.html
> \documentclass[]{article}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
> \usepackage{tikz}
> \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
> \begin{document}
>
> % l' unite
> \newcommand{\myunit}{1 cm}
> \tikzset{
>     node style sp/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=\myunit},
>     node style ge/.style={circle,minimum size=\myunit},
>     arrow style mul/.style={draw,sloped,midway,fill=white},
>     arrow style plus/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white},
> }
>
> \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
> % les matrices
> \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
> {%
>   a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1p}  \\
>   \node[node style sp] {a_{21}};%
>          & \node[node style sp] {a_{22}};%
>                   & \ldots%
>                            & \node[node style sp] {a_{2p}}; \\
>   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
>   a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{np}  \\
> };
> \node [draw,below=10pt] at (A.south) 
>     { $A$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows} $p$ columns};
>
> \matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter =)] at (6*\myunit,6*\myunit)
> {%
>   b_{11} & \node[node style sp] {b_{12}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{1q}  \\
>   b_{21} & \node[node style sp] {b_{22}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{2q}  \\
>   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
>   b_{p1} & \node[node style sp] {b_{p2}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{pq}  \\
> };
> \node [draw,above=10pt] at (B.north) 
>     { $B$ : $p$ rows \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
> % matrice rÃƒÂ©sultat
> \matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter = )] at (6*\myunit,0)
> {%
>   c_{11} & c_{12} & \ldots & c_{1q} \\
>   c_{21} & \node[node style sp,red] {c_{22}};%
>                   & \ldots & c_{2q} \\
>   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>   c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \ldots & c_{nq} \\
> };
> % les fleches
> \draw[blue] (A-2-1.north) -- (C-2-2.north);
> \draw[blue] (A-2-1.south) -- (C-2-2.south);
> \draw[blue] (B-1-2.west)  -- (C-2-2.west);
> \draw[blue] (B-1-2.east)  -- (C-2-2.east);
> \draw[<->,red](A-2-1) to[in=180,out=90]
>   node[arrow style mul] (x) {$a_{21}\times b_{12}$} (B-1-2);
> \draw[<->,red](A-2-2) to[in=180,out=90]
>   node[arrow style mul] (y) {$a_{22}\times b_{22}$} (B-2-2);
> \draw[<->,red](A-2-4) to[in=180,out=90]
>   node[arrow style mul] (z) {$a_{2p}\times b_{p2}$} (B-4-2);
> \draw[red,->] (x) to node[arrow style plus] {$+$} (y)%
>                   to node[arrow style plus] {$+\raisebox{.5ex}{\ldots}+$} (z)%
>                   to (C-2-2.north west);
>
>
> \node [draw,below=10pt] at (C.south) 
>     {$ C=A\times B$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows}  \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
>
> \end{tikzpicture}
>
> \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
> % unit
> % defintion of matrices
> \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
> {%
>   a_{11} &\ldots & a_{1k} & \ldots & a_{1p}  \\
>     \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
>   \node[node style sp] {a_{i1}};& \ldots%
>          & \node[node style sp] {a_{ik}};%
>                   & \ldots%
>                            & \node[node style sp] {a_{ip}}; \\
>   \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
>   a_{n1}& \ldots & a_{nk} & \ldots & a_{np}  \\
> };
> \node [draw,below] at (A.south) { $A$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows} $p$ columns};
> \matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter =)] at (7*\myunit,7*\myunit)
> {%
>   b_{11} &  \ldots& \node[node style sp] {b_{1j}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{1q}  \\
>   \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
>   b_{k1} &  \ldots& \node[node style sp] {b_{kj}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{kq}  \\
>   \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>   b_{p1} &  \ldots& \node[node style sp] {b_{pj}};%
>                   & \ldots & b_{pq}  \\
> };
> \node [draw,above] at (B.north) { $B$ : $p$ rows \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
> % matrice resultat
> \matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,%
>              nodes = {node style ge},%
>              left delimiter  = (,%
>              right delimiter = )] at (7*\myunit,0)
> {%
>   c_{11} & \ldots& c_{1j} & \ldots & c_{1q} \\
>   \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
>     c_{i1}& \ldots & \node[node style sp,red] {c_{ij}};%
>                   & \ldots & c_{iq} \\
>   \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>   c_{n1}& \ldots & c_{nk} & \ldots & c_{nq} \\
> };
> \node [draw,below] at (C.south) 
>     {$ C=A\times B$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows}  \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
> % arrows
> \draw[blue] (A-3-1.north) -- (C-3-3.north);
> \draw[blue] (A-3-1.south) -- (C-3-3.south);
> \draw[blue] (B-1-3.west)  -- (C-3-3.west);
> \draw[blue] (B-1-3.east)  -- (C-3-3.east);
> \draw[<->,red](A-3-1) to[in=180,out=90] 
>     node[arrow style mul] (x) {$a_{i1}\times b_{1j}$} (B-1-3);
> \draw[<->,red](A-3-3) to[in=180,out=90] 
>     node[arrow style mul] (y) {$a_{ik}\times b_{kj}$}(B-3-3);
> \draw[<->,red](A-3-5) to[in=180,out=90] 
>     node[arrow style mul] (z) {$a_{ip}\times b_{pj}$}(B-5-3);
> \draw[red,->] (x) to node[arrow style plus] {$+\raisebox{.5ex}{\ldots}+$} (y)%
>                   to node[arrow style plus] {$+\raisebox{.5ex}{\ldots}+$} (z);
>                   %
>                   % to (C-3-3.north west);
> \draw[->,red,decorate,decoration=zigzag] (z) -- (C-3-3.north west);
> \end{tikzpicture}
> \end{document}
>
> % encoding : utf8
> % format   : pdfLaTeX
> % author   : Alain Matthes
> ```